# Can not use code tag

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

With the following question, [Interesting Windows 7 boot Issue involving RAID and an SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/179135/interesting-windows-7-boot-issue-involving-raid-and-an-ssd), I'm not able to remove the quote block in which the code block is embedded. Without making it a quote, the code block won't show as illustrated here: https://superuser.com/posts/179135/revisions (Revisions 3 and 4)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gotcha when dealing with lists and code.

> List items may consist of multiple paragraphs. Each subsequent paragraph in a list item must be indented by either 4 spaces or one tab:

Since code is also indented by 4 spaces/one tab it thinks it's a subsequent paragraph.

> To put a code block within a list item, the code block needs to be indented twice — 8 spaces or two tabs:

[Markdown Syntax: List](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list)

Have edited the fix into the question.

Comment: There's still one thing... it seems as if the code block now has a double indent, in the source as in the normal view... there must be a way to fix this...

Comment: @BloodPhilla: As far as Markdown is concerned it's part of the list item. To stop that you'd need to put a block level element of some kind between the list and code block. Then you can use the code block as you would normally. What I did was just take the last bit of the last point and moved it into a paragraph on it's own to separate the list and the code. Which one do you prefer?