# How to add a code block following a numbered or ordered list

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can not use code tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1311/can-not-use-code-tag)

Just a little quirk I noticed when using the Editor.

### This is bad:

[image: Bad example]

---

### This is good:

[image: Good example]

---

Alternatively, you have to insert a horizontal rule (`---`) between the list and the code block to get it to behave.